# How compiler identifies the ASCII code of multiple characters

Tags: c++, character, ascii

```
int var;
var=' ';       // this is a single space
cout << var;   // prints 32
var = '  ';    // double space
cout << var;   // prints 8224. Why?
```

How the compiler calculates this (8224) for two spaces?

This happens with every multi-character literal.

Comment: *How* do you "give two spaces"?

Comment: when i write var='  '; i am giving two spaces between single quotes.

Comment: So a multi-character literal? Then it's implementation specific. What the result will be depends on the compiler you are using. See e.g. [this character literal reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is what C++ standard N3690 mentions about multicharacter literals:

> An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a **multicharacter** literal. A multicharacter literal, or an ordinary character literal containing a single c-char not representable in the execution character
>   set, is conditionally-supported, has type int, and has an **implementation**-defined value.

So the answer is that the corresponding int value is *implementation-specific*.

While for single-char literal:

> An ordinary character literal that contains a single c-char representable in the execution character set has type char, with value equal to the numerical value of the encoding of the c-char in the execution character set.

Answer (score 0):

a char in c++ is a **byte**(with possible int values from **0** to **255**).
So in your case when you cast the two white-spaces '  ' to an int, behind the scenes it's just a **base-256 conversion**. To be more precise:

- the white-space ' ' has an ASCII of 32.
- So, two white-spaces will be cast to an int of: 32 + 256*32 = 8224.

**EDIT**

- this is how your two characters are represented in memory, where one char-block is a byte, which can have values ranging in 0-255: 
  **|char| char|**.
- when you cast this two blocks to an int, you make a base-256 conversion, i.e. the ASCII of the right char block, which is 32 we multiply by 256^0. Then the ASCII of the next char block, i.e. 32 we multiply by 256^1.
- Step 2. is **implementation dependent** as @saurav-sahu mentions, e.g. if it's [big endian or little endian](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-15/ass15_3.html).
- I tried to give you an intuition of what goes behind the system, but as [pete_becker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593860/pete-becker) has correctly pointed to, it's **highly implementation specific**, e.g. the char type can be interpreted as a signed or unsigned value and so on.

Comment: can you explain this more.

Comment: A `char` can be signed or unsigned; either way, it is **not** required to hold values from 0 to 255. When it's unsigned, that's quite common, but, again, not required.

Comment: The value of a multi-character literal (as in `'  '`) is **implementation-defined**. That means that the implementation **must document** what it does. The value is not required to be some more-or-less literal interpretation of values in memory, and it may or may not have anything to do with endianness.